# Jquery append dynamic div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to append a table row with an ID to another table. I have the following code:

```
var ID = jQuery.inArray(name, name_array);
$("#processed").append('#'+ID);
```

The following code does not work, as it only shows `#1`, `#2`, and so on (instead of the div with that ID). The table row that I am trying to move ID is set at the first line, but the second does not work.

 How can I append it?
Thanks!

Comment: $.inArray() returns the index of name in name_array (hence you #1, #2...) [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/]. Can you explain what you name and name_array are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can all be wrapped to one line actually:

`$("#processed").append(jQuery('<tr />', { id: ('#' + jQuery.inArray(name, name_array)), name: name });`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = jQuery.inArray(name, name_array);
$("#processed").append($('<div/>', { id: '#'+ID }));
```

Comment: This does not seem to do anything :S